# How to add bold text to rich text box

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working with Visual Studio Express 2012 with C#.

I am using code to add text to a `RichTextBox`. Each time there are 2 lines added. The first line needs to be bold and the second line normal.

Here is the only thing I could think to try, even though I was sure it would not work:

```
this.notes_pnl.Font = new Font(this.notes_pnl.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
this.notes_pnl.Text += tn.date.ToString("MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss")  + Environment.NewLine;
this.notes_pnl.Font = new Font(this.notes_pnl.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
this.notes_pnl.Text += tn.text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
```

How can I add bolded lines to a rich text box?

Thanks for the answers submitted so far. I think I need to clarify a little.
I am not adding these 2 lines 1 time. I will be adding the lines several times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to make the text bold you just need to surround the text with `\b` and use the `Rtf` member.

```
this.notes_pln.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi this word is \b bold \b0 }";
```

OP mentioned that they will be adding lines over time.  If that is the case then this could be abstracted away into a class

```
class RtfBuilder { 
  StringBuilder _builder = new StringBuilder();

  public void AppendBold(string text) { 
    _builder.Append(@"\b ");
    _builder.Append(text);
    _builder.Append(@"\b0 ");
  }

  public void Append(string text) { 
    _builder.Append(text);
  }

  public void AppendLine(string text) { 
    _builder.Append(text);
    _builder.Append(@"\line");
  }

  public string ToRtf() { 
    return @"{\rtf1\ansi " + _builder.ToString() + @" }";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it appears I cannot append 1 line at a time with this. When I try 'this.notes_pnl.Rtf +=' nothing is displayed.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss once you start using `rtf` you should use it for all notations including line breaks.  Using `\line` should break the lines

Comment: Thanks. The issue is I will be adding lines several time at different times, so I need to append the text to previous text.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss editted my answer to describe how you could build up lines over time with a builder class

Comment: public string ToRtf() { 
    return @"{\rtf1\ansi " + _builder.ToString() + @" }";
  }

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Rtf property of your `RichTextBox`. First generate an rtf string:

```
var rtf = string.Format(@"{{\rtf1\ansi \b {0}\b0 \line {1}\line\line }}",
                          tn.date.ToString("MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss"), 
                          tn.text);
```

And append the string to the existing text in your `RichTextBox`:

```
this.notes_pln.SelectionStart = this.notes_pln.TextLength;
this.notes_pln.SelectedRtf = rtf;
```